# How to add an Image to a plane that has a boolean modifier applied?

Tags: materials, uv, modifiers, uv-image-editor

I merged two plains so I can later rig it into a paper folder animation. I used the boolean modifier to unite the two plains. When I go into edit mode the two plains can still be selected individually so I then mapped an image onto one of the faces and the image shows up on the other face too. I haven't made any seams since the plains are still individual units inside edit mode. Any suggestions?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure it's clear from the questions what your aim is.

Asuming you'd like more control over how images are displayed on the final object I'd go with one of two options:

- Apply the boolean modifier and work with separate faces in *Edit mode*
- Use the same material to both planes (bool operands) **but** have different UV mappings for them, so that you can use separate areas of your image to texture the final united plane.

In the example below I did this to both planes with the same image texture applied (same material). However, one plane has UV square on the left side of the image while the other plane has UV on the right side.

You can hide the second plane and the final object would still look the same.

You could do different things then:

- Shrink one of the UVs to a pixel sized square and locate it over the needed color to have a mono-coloured part

OR

- Scale UV by -1 to reverse the mirror effect you have on your screenshot.

Hope this helps.

[image: Different UVs for initial planes]